# Print a BST in the REPL?

Tags: common-lisp, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to get a binary search tree's struct print function as below to print out a node (with its children, recursively) in an xml-ish style. The idea being that adding appropriate indentation should make it easier to see the structure of the BST.

What I have currently is:

```lisp
(defstruct
  (node (:print-function
          (lambda (n s d)      
            (format s "#<~A ~A ~A>" (node-elt n) (node-l n) (node-r n)))))
  elt (l nil) (r nil))
```

This prints out a BST as, for example:

```
#<5 #<4 #<2 #<1 NIL NIL> #<3 NIL NIL>> NIL> #<8 #<6 NIL #<7 NIL NIL>> #<9 NIL NIL>>>
```

But I'd like something from which it is easier to visualise the tree structure.

I have something like this in mind:

```
#<5 
 #<4 
  #<2 
   #<1 NIL NIL> 
   #<3 NIL NIL>> NIL> 
 #<8 
  #<6 NIL 
   #<7 NIL NIL>> 
  #<9 NIL NIL>>>
```

Assuming my goal is a good one, the indentation depth of each line must depend on the depth of the recursion. I'm not sure how to do that within the `format` form above.

Actually, maybe this isn't a very good way to display it after all.

If not, what is a good way to print out a (small, of course) binary search tree in the REPL, such that one can easily see its structure? (as a tool to help with algorithm development).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use logical blocks.

```
(defstruct
    (node
      (:constructor bst (elt &optional l r))
      (:print-function
         (lambda (n s d)
           (declare (ignore d))
           (format s
                   "(~s ~@<~s ~_~s ~_~s)~:>"
                   'bst
                   (node-elt n) (node-l n) (node-r n)))))
  elt (l nil) (r nil))
```

When you call [`PPRINT-LOGICAL-BLOCK`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_ppr_lo.htm), the stream being used becomes a [*pretty-printing stream*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#pretty_printing_stream) during the extent of the block (if it is not already one). Functions that start with `pprint-` like `pprint-newline` or `pprint-indent` respect indentation levels, logical blocks, etc. Usual functions like  `terpri` or `fresh-line` do not.

The above format defines a logical block after `bst`, and prints conditional newlines between each element. The added value of this particular printer is that it prints the form readably.

#### Input

Thanks to the `:constructor` option, we can write a BST as follows:

```
(bst t
     (bst 1 (bst :x) (bst :y))
     (bst 2 (bst :a) (bst :b)))
```

#### Printed result

When evaluated, the resulting tree is printed in a way that can be read back to produce an equivalent tree.

```
(BST T
     (BST 1 (BST :X NIL NIL) (BST :Y NIL NIL))
     (BST 2 (BST :A NIL NIL) (BST :B NIL NIL)))
```

#### Alternative printer

You could also define a printer that just prints the form using an intermediate list. This is simpler to write and relies on existing pretty print functions.

```
(defstruct
        (node
          (:constructor bst (elt &optional l r))
          (:print-function
             (lambda (n s d)
               (declare (ignore d))
               (princ (list 'bst
                            (node-elt n)
                            (node-l n)
                            (node-r n))
                      s))))
      elt (l nil) (r nil))
```

#### Output for modified printer

```
(BST T (BST 1 (BST X NIL NIL) (BST Y NIL NIL))
     (BST 2 (BST A NIL NIL) (BST B NIL NIL)))
```